# Is there a trick to use a opengl 3.x version program on a graphics card which supports opengl 2.x?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I have a onboard graphics card which supports opengl 2.2. Can I run a opengl (let's say 3.3 version) application on it by using some software etc?

Comment: Not certain, but I doubt it. The primary software implementation of OpenGL is Mesa3D, which currently only supports up though OpenGL 2.x.

Comment: For what reason, may I ask, do you want to run a OpenGL 3.0 program with an on-board video card?

Comment: There is no OpenGL 2.2 (only 2.1).

Comment: @yser978122, I have a o/b graphics card (supports only opengl2.1) so I can't change the graphics card and what only I can do is to buy a new laptop. Therefore, I'm seeking for a trick.

Comment: The trick is well suggested below by "ssube".

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL major versions somewhat refer to available hardware capabilities:

- OpenGL-1: fixed function pipeline (DirectX 7 class HW)
- OpenGL-2: programmable vertex and fragment shader support.(DirectX 9 class HW)
- OpenGL-3: programmable geometry shader support (DirectX 10 class HW)
- OpenGL-4: programmable tesselation shader support and a few other nice things (DirectX 11 class HW).

If your GPU supports OpenGL-2 only, then there is no way you could run a OpenGL-3 program, making use of all whistles and bells on it. Your best bet is a software rasterizing implementation.

---

*A few years ago, when shders were something new, NVidia shipped their developer drivers with some higher functionality emulation software rasterizer, to kickstart shader development, so that there were actual applications to run on those new programmable GPUs.*

Comment: A bit of a rigid answer, since it actually depends if the "OpenGL 3.3 program" in question really uses GL3 hardware features.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I did write "a OpenGL-3 program, making use of all whistles and bells", i.e. the full functionality. Of course you could still use a subset of extensions to OpenGL-2, being part of OpenGL-3, that the implementation in question supports.

Comment: It may be worth updating your answer about software rasterizer, since Mesa software renderers now [fully support OpenGL 3.3](https://mesamatrix.net/) (core profile only, and multisampling is still fake).

Comment: Well, in my particular case, I have a laptop with Intel integrated graphics, and it supports DirectX 10, but it doesn't support OpenGL above 2.1 -- seems like they never made the drivers for it. By the way with DirectX, there is an option in Windows to emulate DX11 graphics with just DX10 hardware (albeit extremely slow, but probably serviceable for "rendering a triangle" tutorials). This makes me curious if there would be something similar for OpenGL.

Comment: @lalilulelost: With OpenGL you can always use the Mesa software rasterizer, which is kind of the same as the DX11 emulation you mentioned. Also DX10 is somewhere between OpenGL-2 and OpenGL-3. Very likely you'll find a couple of OpenGL extensions that go beyond OpenGL-2 and give you the rest of the functionality to reach feature parity with DX10. – With OpenGL it never has been this "all or nothing" situation, like with DX, where it all comes down to particular versions. So just have a look at the list of supported extensions and see if it contains what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, you just have to disable those features. Whether this will work well depends greatly on the app.

The simplest method is to intercept all OpenGL calls, using some manner of DLL hooking, and filter them as necessary. When OGL3 features are used, return a "correct" answer (but don't do anything) or provide null for calls that aren't required.

If done properly, and the app isn't relying on the OGL3 features, this will run without those on your hardware.

If the app does require OGL3 stuff, results will be unreliable at best, and it may be unusable. It really depends on what exactly the app does and what it needs. Providing a null implementation of OGL3 will allow you to *run* it, but results are up in the air.

Comment: Off course this is incorrect. There are no ways to run a 3.x opengl application on a card that doesn't support it

Comment: @VJo Sure there is. The same way the application is not aware whether it's running on actual hardware or a reference rasterizer, you can provide an intercept-and-modify layer, adding or removing features as you please. If you prevent those calls, then it will run. How well it will functional is the only major question.

Comment: You mean SW rendering. I haven't heard of one supporting opengl 3. btw I tried this last week, and my application didn't run at all, because of unsupported extensions.

Comment: @VJo No, not using software rendering, using the same *concept*. The application doesn't know exactly what it's running on, the API and drivers both abstract that. If you tell the application what it wants to hear and do something different, it *may never know*. This trick has been used for years in graphics upgrades, testing, **and is the basis of graphics drivers**.

Comment: -1: This doesn't answer _the question_. Doing what you suggest will _not_ cause his 2.1 graphics card to render 3.3 images. Indeed, it wouldn't even cause 3.3 calls to work, because you clearly point out that this would just swallow the 3.3 calls. He wants to actually use OpenGL with 3.3, not call functions that don't do anything

Comment: @NicolBolas The question only asks if he can *run* it, which is what I answered.

Comment: @VJo The real question is, does this "OpenGL 3.3 program" actually use any OpenGL 3 features or not? Of course when you call it an "OpenGL 3.3 program" you assume it does, but does the OP, too?

Comment: Trying to use opengl 3.x functions with a card that doesn't support opengl 3.x is going to cause a segmentation fault. Simple as that. I do not consider programs that fall back to opengl 2.1

Comment: @VJo Which is why you prevent those calls from reaching the actual hardware, and handle them in a different level (whether that involves software processing or simply discarding). There are a number of ways to safely upgrade and downgrade graphics using interception.

Comment: @peachykeen: I assume that when someone says that they want to "run" something, that they want it to actually do what it's supposed to. Not show a black screen. You can get _anything_ to run if you define "run" so broadly that simply not erroring is considered running.

Comment: @peachykeen: And interception is generally the worst way to downgrade graphics. A better way is to actually do it in your program. For example, let's say I use pass a `#version 330` shader. For you to "downgrade" that shader, you must actually detect the version number, replace various grammar with version 120 grammar, and somehow replace use of things that 120 doesn't have (like geometry shaders, integer textures, etc) with things that it does. That's non-trivial, and it would be much easier to do if you're actually writing the program in question.

Comment: @NicolBolas As I said in the answer, what happens very much depends on the app and what it uses, and it very well may not work. Still a method worth attempting IMO, as it may work.

Comment: Whoa guys, you are in quite long debate. Let me explain briefly what I ask: I have a graphics card which supports Opengl2.1. Let's assume, I have a c++ code and shaders (fragment and vertex shaders) and I build it on my machine. Normally, the .exe (or .o) output won't run in my machine because my graphics card doesn't support pipeline programming. Therefore, I'm searching for an application which takes .exe and shader files and somehow renders, displays as if I have a graphics card supporting 3.x. Is it possible?

Comment: @CihadTurhan: As both datenwolf and I stated, no, you cannot. You might be able to with NVIDIA's through NVemulate, but even that's kind of a long shot.

Comment: @NicolBolas, thank you. I've already looked for a new laptop. :(

Comment: What @ssube explained is totally worth to try, and of course is a need in some cases. You would not pay $$$ for a new laptop or video cards etc in many cases in which there is no real need to any new feature from newer opengl. Cases that you just want the application to run and do not exit because the requested version of opengl is not present on the device.

Answer (score 0):

No. Well, not really. NVIDIA has some software emulation that might work, but other than that, no.

Your hardware simply can't do what GL 3.0+ asks of it.

also:

> I have a onboard graphics card which supports opengl 2.2

There is no OpenGL 2.2. Perhaps you meant 2.1.

Comment: Sorry, it's opengl 2.1. And my last hope is gone now. It's time to buy a new laptop whose gfx card supports 3.x or 4.x :(

Comment: This is not an answer but just comment, which are not correct either.

Comment: @Developer: The OP asked if a program written against GL 3.3 can be run on hardware that only supports GL 2.1. The answer to that is "No".

Comment: @NicolBolas As in ssube's answer there is definitely a workaround to achieve this, hence the answer cannot be "No". While it might require hardworking dealing with drivers etc but it is worth to try. If succeed it is a big success, indeed. Apparently, there are hardware companies that do not like this idea. However, we do not have to worry about them. If I could find time I would definitely dig deeper and publish anything found to public.

Comment: "... and the answer is no." Even your own answer contradicts: "...NVIDIA has some software emulation that might work". So, why MESA with software rendering is not a valid answer to the original question (which was not concerned with performance)?